# How to compare selected keys of different objects javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to compare some selected fields of two objects.

E.g

```
const a = {type: "media", value: "TV"}
const b = {type: "media", value: "TV", name: "John"}
```

Can we have something to compare these two object with some specific keys like

```
const keys = [type, value]
compare(a, b, keys);
```

I just need to know some best practices to handle this logic and wants to avoid simple loops. 
Do we have any lodash lib for that ? Or any JavaScript ES6 function.

FYI: this is just simple example my real time scenario are far very complex.

Updates: 
This is what I have tried

Values are coming from react state and I am building my object E.g

```
const myObject = {a: aVal, b: bVal, c: cVal .......}
const compareObject = compareObject.exclude(the keys which I dont need) // example

const result = isEqual(myObject, compareObject)
```

Thanks

Comment: what result do you expect? a boolean value? what have you tried?

Comment: Yes boolean. 
Let me update my question about what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) to get the properties from the 2nd object (`b`), and then use [`_.isMatch()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isMatch) to make a partial deep comparison of the values (only the values of `b` that exist in `a`).

**Note:** `_.isEqual()` will work for nest structures as well - see the comparison between a & c.

```js
const compare = (a, b, keys) => _.isMatch( // check deep equality
  a, // get properties from a
  _.pick(b, keys), // get properties from b
)

const a = { type: "media", value: "TV", name: { first: "John" } };
const b = { type: "media", value: "TV", name: "John" };
const c = { type: "media", value: "TV", name: { first: "John" } };

console.log(compare(a, b, ['type', 'value'])); //  true
console.log(compare(a, b, ['type', 'name']));  // false
console.log(compare(a, c, ['type', 'name']));  // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could check every property of both objects.

```js
const
    compare = (a, b, keys) => keys.every(k => a[k] === b[k]),
    a = { type: "media", value: "TV" },
    b = { type: "media", value: "TV", name: "John" };

console.log(compare(a, b, ['type', 'value'])); //  true
console.log(compare(a, b, ['type', 'name']));  // false
```